# Is a Silo Landing Page reserved for static Pages only or can Blog/Product Categories be used as a Silo instead?

Tags: seo, site-structure

I am aware that a Silo structure, is a way to logically organise website content; with vertical linking, within each Silo, helping visitors and search engines understand a site's overall theme(s)/Topic(s).

Furthermore, I understand there are 2 approaches to creating a Silo:

- **Physical Silo:**  This being the directory structure of the URL.
- **Virtual Silo:**  This being the internal linking structure.

Having come across Silo examples online, I can see that many suggest that a Silo is a Static Page, with Blog/Products Categories and their respective Posts and Products with each Silo.

If this is the case, what are the implications when it comes to Taxonomies/URL structures; since Pages are a different Taxonomy to Categories & Posts/Products.

Is it a case that a Silo is excluded from the URL structure, relying on a Virtual Silo to 'make the link' to the Category pages or is it a case that a Silo is in fact a Category page?

Comment: Now you are overthinking this. The term silo is a B.S. SEO term. Get from the concept what makes sense to you and then chuck the rest. In the end, do what makes sense from an organizational point of view. Common sense is what is needed. Pleased do not go too far down a rabbit hole that is just painted on the ground. Cheers!!

Comment: Using WordPress, I feel that the Blog/Product Category Taxonomy creates a Silo structure by design.  All you have to do, is to then ensure the internal linking is logical.  That said, I see a lot of resources saying that Pages are the Silos which then link to the Categories.  Seems like overkill to me; to create a Static Page with the primary focus of it replacing the Category Page as the top level 'Silo'.

Comment: Creation of a site properly organized is a silo organized site when you get right down to it. This is why the term silo is a B.S. term. And one reason why I tell you to simply organize the site in a way that makes sense. SEOs often over think things to the point of ridiculous when common sense is often all that is needed. Cheers!!